# Generation of power using multiple step up transformers

Tags: transformer, generator, power-engineering

Why do we need huge generators to produce electricity? Is it not possible to use a small generator to produce a small voltage and then use multiple transformers to step it up?

Comment: NO @glenn review transformer theory.  Turns ratio raises impedance by  n² and thus load /source impedance ratio affects regulation so voltage drops drastically . A true voltage source has 0 impedance , but practical units are 2 to 10% Zo in units by ratio source impedance of the V/I expressed as a ratio per unit (p.u.) This affects short circuit current and load regulation.. A tiny unit has relatively high impedance which rises with n²  turns ratio. as such steel core transformer and generators must be forllow a kW/kg rule of thumb, which is why 100MVA units weigh many tons.

Comment: Why do ocean going liners have massive engines?

Comment: Just go through the theory of conservation of Energy once.

Answer (score 2):

Transformers pass power (voltage times current).  The output power will always be slightly less than the input power due to losses in the transformer.

If the transformer increases the voltage, the available current will be reduced by the same ratio (ignoring losses).

Answer (score 0):

The average power station generator can be 100+ Megawatts (There are single generators that will do over a Gigawatt!) Voltages of 25'000V are not uncommon, so that means you can be getting some 4000 amps from one... *just one*, a large power station could have a dozen. The Three Gorges Dam in China can produce some *20'000 Megawatts* at it's peak.

Their size is dependent on a mix of voltage isolation, having sufficient room for all the windings (think 30mm solid bar), cooling constraints, even lifespan, because while it's quite possible to make more compact generators, their lifespans may be degraded due to things like higher heat flux, increased mechanical loading due to smaller bearings etc.

As for why such high voltages are used, resistive power loss scales with the *square* of the current so if you halved the voltage you would need twice the current for the same power capacity (P = I*V) but you would have *4 times* the resistive power loss (P_loss = I^2*R). As for why the generators might be 25kV and not 50kV, that comes down to how much insulation you can practically fit into the generator. Higher current needs thicker windings and more cooling, higher voltage needs thicker insulation (and adding more insulation can make cooling harder as electrical insulators tend to also be *thermal insulators*)

As for why bigger generators are used instead of multiple step-up stages... which do you think costs more? A single 100MW generator or a single 100MW generator and several step-up transformers? The world is a power hungry place so we need big generators and like most things, it's cheaper to build big thanks to the economies of scale.